# Yii2 action column calling controller action without url/routing

Tags: gridview, yii2

as newbie to web developing i face several walls to climb over. Some i can handle by myself with web researches and so on, for the rest i have to ask more experienced developers like you.

I am facing a problem with a grid view and the action column buttons and changing values in the database and refresh the partial view. I want to make a "joblist", where jobs will be started when created (not implemented yet) and then they can be paused, un-paused and stopped and updating the datetime in the database.

I solved it with the help of internet researches, but only with an URL-routing, which calls the action and routes to it (e.g. index.php?r=site%2Fstart&id=2). But i want it only to refresh the partial view and change the database.

So i think my problem is the way i call the action via routing, but i dont find another "working" way. I also tried with javascript, but i have problems with handing over values (as my experience with javascript is at least 2 weeks old).

So i hope someone can give me the correct push in the right way to solve this problem. I do not want a complete solution, just some hints and code snippets to get the whole damn thing working as intended. Perhaps i am just searching for the wrong keywords in the web and for that i am not finding solutions. Everything will help me to learn more and more.

In the first code snippet of my partial view, i will get a grid view from my jobs table from the database and update status (paused or stopped - running will be done logically).

```
<?php


use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;


?>
    GRIDVIEW JOBSLIST


<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create new Job', ['/jobs/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderJobs,

    'columns' => [

        [
                'label' => 'User',
                'attribute' => 'parentid2.username',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) { 
            return Html::a($model->parentId2->username, ['/employees/view', 'id' => $model->parentId2->id]);
            },
        ],


        'job_description:ntext',
        'finished_flag',
        'jobs_paused',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',

        'template' => '{start}{pause}{stop}',
        'buttons' => [

                'start' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if($model->jobs_paused==1)
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Starten'),
                        ]);
                },

                'pause' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if($model->jobs_paused==0 && !$model->finished_flag==1)
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Pausieren'),
                        ]);
                },

                'stop' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if($model->jobs_paused==0 && $model->finished_flag==0)
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Abschließen'),
                        ]);
                },
      ],

      'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model) {
            if ($action === 'start') {
                $url =Url::toRoute(['site/start', 'id' => $model->id]);
                return $url;
        }
            if ($action === 'pause') {
                $url =Url::toRoute(['site/pause', 'id' => $model->id]);
                return $url;
        }
            if ($action === 'stop') {
                $url =Url::toRoute(['site/stop', 'id' => $model->id]);
                return $url;
        }
      }
     ],
            ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

At second my controller "site" with my 3 actions (start, pause and stop) which will/should update the database values.

```
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{


// Play, Pause, Stop of Joblist

public function actionStart($id)
{

    $jobstart = Jobs::findOne($id); 
    $jobstart->unpause_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()); 
    $jobstart->jobs_paused = 0; 
    $jobstart->save(false); echo "Neue Zeit gespeichert " . $jobstart->unpause_time; 

}

public function actionPause($id)
{

    $jobpause = Jobs::findOne($id);
    $jobpause->pause_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
    $jobpause->jobs_paused = 1;
    $jobpause->save(false);

}

public function actionStop($id)
{

    $jobstop = Jobs::findOne($id); 
    $jobstop->end_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()); 
    $jobstop->finished_flag = 1; 
    $jobstop->save(false); 

}

}
```

And at last i show my main view the containers for better understanding.

```
 <?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Produktivumgebung';
?>

<div id="prodoutside" style="background-color:blue; position:relative; padding: 10px">

<div class="leftside">
<!--        // Container oben links für Übersicht und Suche-->
        <div id="upperleft" class="col-md-6 prodleft">

            <?php 
                echo $this->renderAjax('//site/frames/_customerssearch', ['model' => $searchModel]);?>

            <?php echo $this->renderAjax('//site/frames/_upperleft', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'searchModel' => $searchModel)); ?>
        </div>

</div>


    <div class="rightside">
<!--        // Container oben rechts für Jobliste-->
        <div id="upperright" class="col-md-6 prodright">

            <?php echo $this->renderAjax('//site/frames/_upperright', array(
                'modelJobs' => $modelJobs,
                'dataProviderJobs' => $dataProviderJobs,
                'searchModelJobs' => $searchModelJobs)); ?>
        </div>


<!--        //Container unten links für Detailview-->
        <div id="lowerright" class="col-md-6 prodright">
            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->renderAjax('//site/frames/_lowerright', array(
                'model2' => $model2)); ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think you can use ajax via jQuery, so you can read the documentation about it -> [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: what's the current behavior of your grid if you click one of the action buttons?

Comment: Currently it opens a white page (index.php?r=site%2Fstart&id=2) and stays there. If i press the back button it gets back to the site and the database as the action buttons are updated.